# Python Linkedin, How to share content on user's wall

Tags: python, python-2.7, linkedin-api

I am building an app which allow signing in through Linkedin. I am not using linkedin api..
So what i do is take the user through authentication process and in the end generate an authentication token (OAuth2)....
Using this token i get its updates and connection details...using urlib

```
url = "https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/network/updates?type=SHAR&count=50&start=50&oauth2_access_token=XXXX"
lp = urllib2.urlopen(url)
```

Now what i need to do is Share on user's wall using this token. I already have rw_nus access when i logged in the user...
In the documentation it is mentioned to use link "http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/shares" but i am a bit confused on how to send share content which is JSON on this url using the token... i am doing as below

```
share_object = {
"comment":"comment_text",
"content": {
    "title":"Test",
    "submitted_url":"http://www.test.com/",
},
"visibility": {
    "code": "anyone"
}
}
api_url = "http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/shares?oauth2_access_token=XXXX";

data = json.dumps(share_object)
req = urllib2.Request(api_url, data, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
f = urllib2.urlopen(req)
response = f.read()
f.close()
```

its giving this error in the line: `f = urllib2.urlopen(req)`

```
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized
```

Comment: why are you not using the Linkedin API client?

Comment: If i have the authentication token then how will i do the above sharing process using Linkedin API client??

Comment: All the linkedin clients i have searched are using Oauth but i have generated the token using Oauth2.. I haven't found any client or api which is using Oauth2...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote below function to share content on Linkedin using OAuth2

```
import requests
import json
def make_request(method, url, token ,data=None, params=None, headers=None, timeout=60):
    headers = {'x-li-format': 'json', 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
    params = {} 
    kw = dict(data=data, params=params, headers=headers, timeout=timeout)
    params.update({'oauth2_access_token': token})
    return requests.request(method.upper(), url, **kw)   

def submit_share(comment, title, description, submitted_url, submitted_image_url, token):
    post = {
        'comment': comment,
        'content': {
        'title': title,
        'submitted-url': submitted_url,
        'submitted-image-url': submitted_image_url,
        'description': description
    },
    'visibility': {
        'code': 'anyone'
    }
    }
    url = 'https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/shares'
    try:
        response = make_request('POST', url, token,data=json.dumps(post))
        response = response.json()
        return response
    except Exception:
        return False
```

I hope it helps somebody.
Regards